# Wrong RTP packet sequence received

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, odroid

I am using this pipeline to stream h264 with gstreamer but I get this very strange error. I've not found anything related to it.

Pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264, payload=96" port=5002 ! cvartprawdepay2 verbose=FALSE check-rtp=TRUE  ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,width=640,height=480 ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=FALSE
```

resulting error:

> WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpRawDepay2:rtprawdepay2-0: h264_process: Wrong RTP packet sequence received.

I'm using an odroid with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does this happen every time? UDP is out-of-order, and old packets (with old sequence number) could be dropped.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried another pipeline without "cvartprawdepay2 verbose=FALSE check-rtp=TRUE  " and using "rtph264depay" instead and it works. maybe there is a problem in camera configuration, I'm going to check, thank u

Comment: is the cvartprawdepay2 supposed to be rtpvrawpay? is this gstreamer 0.10 ? I could not find anything on such element.. guess its just a typo. as its udp maybe there are dropouts on your network.. bu as its h264 encoded how can it be payloaded as raw? the rtph264depay really makes more sense

Comment: cvartdepay is a particular plugin developed by the duy that has given me the camera, so it can't be found easily in Internet. I have checked the camera configuration with him and I have found the problem :) anyway thank you